# How can I avoid font size problems with HTML buttons?

Tags: android, html

I am constructing a static HTML web page that integrates audio play-buttons into text paragraphs, which uses inline click buttons to hear the following word. There is a problem that paragraphs containing play buttons may display at a too-small size, so I want to correct that. Here is a screen shot of the problem:

[image]

The problem only arises with Chrome on Android (no problem on Mac, Windows, Windows Chrome, Android Firefox or Android Opera). I am aware of ‘Responsive Web Design’ and the viewport from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). The problem seems to be caused by the button tag. Here is a snippet of code, online at
https://languagedescriptions.github.io/IP3/minpage.html.

```
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script>function playAudio(audio_element) {var x = document.getElementById(audio_element);
x.play();}</script></head>

<body><p>This paragraph has just ordinary text, and it displays correctly.</p>

<p>This paragraph contains a play-button
<audio id="dog" src="ch1dog.wav"></audio>
<button onclick="playAudio('dog')" type="button">play</button>
which causes the text to shrink.</p></body></html>
```

I assume this arises because the bounding box for the button is greater than the text, and Android Chrome handles the paragraph differently from other browsers. I want to correct this, but I don’t know what I should have set that would fix this. It is important to the functioning of the page that the thing which users click be treated like ordinary text (not relegated to sidebars, separate paragraphs, tables etc). It should be something that users can intuitively associate with the concept “click to play”, like a button or the character ►. Either (1), is there some attribute that I can specify for the button tag which corrects the information that Android Chrome fills in or (2) is there some way to make an iconic character like ► have the onclick attribute, thus avoiding the button?

Comment: I don't understand which is the problem. I've opened your snipped link and, on my Dekstop Firefox, the page is exactly the same of your screenshot. Reading your HTML code what we get is exaclty what we could expect........so I don't figure out the issue.....

Comment: It works correctly on Firefox, it is apparently a problem with Android Chrome that I'm trying to overcome. The screen shot above shows that the second paragraph shrinks in size but no code directly does that. You can open the link if you have an Android device with Chrome and I'm pretty sure it will replicate, it has for a half-dozen devices that I've tested.

Comment: @user6727 I opened on Android Chrome and I see exactly the same behaviour of Destop Firefox and Desktop Chrome.....which are all the same of your screenshot (beside that the first paragraph font-size, in your screenshot, seems bigger then in mine)